# What are online down-scaling algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, embedded, microcontroller, scaling

I'm building a circuit that will be reading PAL/NTSC (576i, 480i) frames from analog input. The microcontroller has 32 kB of memory. My goal is to scale down input to 32x16 resolution, and forward this image to LED matrix.

PAL frame can take ~400 kB of memory. So i thought about down-scaling online. Read 18 pixels, decimate to 1. Read 45 lines, decimate to 1. Peak memory usage: 45 x 32 = 1.44 kB (45 decimated lines awaiting decimation).

Question: What are other online image down-scaling algorithms, other than the above naive one? Googling is extremely hard because online services are being found (PDF resize, etc.)

Comment: You should probably start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling). Pay special attention to `Image scaling can be interpreted as a form of image resampling or image reconstruction under consideration of the Nyquist sampling theorem. According to the theorem the down sampling to a smaller image from a higher-resolution original should be only carried out only after applying a suitable 2D anti-aliasing filter to prevent aliasing artifacts. The image is reduced to the information which can be carried by the smaller image.`

Answer (score -1):

Note that mentioned formats are interlaced, so you read at first 0th, 2nd, 4th.. lines (first semi-frame), then 1st, 3rd, .. lines (second semi-frame).

If you are using simple averaging of pixel values in resulting cell (I suspect it is OK for so small output matrix), then create output array (16x32=512 entries) and sum appropriate values for every cell. And you need buffer for a single input line (768 or 640 entries).

```
x_coeff = input_width / out_width
y_coeff = input_height / out_height
out_y = inputrow / y_coeff
for (inputcol = 0..input_width - 1)
    out_x = inputcol / x_coeff
    out_array[out_y][out_x] += input_line[inputcol]
inputrow = inputrow + 2
if (inputrow = input_height)
   inputrow = 1  
if (inputrow > input_height)
     inputrow = 0  
     divide out_array[][] entries by ( x_coeff * y_coeff)
```